# post thumbnail size too small

Tags: php, wordpress, media

I set in my functions.php the size to display my posts thumbnails like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 960, 540, true );
```

The problem is that they won't go bigger than 922px wide for some reason, I if I set them smaller than 922 they will show up accordingly, but not bigger.

I'm working on a child theme of Wordpress Twenty Thirteen, perhaps its something within the theme?

Here is the link to the site, zoom out to see what happens when they get bigger than 922 px.
www.fredericdesign.net/newsite

Comment: Your images are only 922px wide.

Comment: They are all sized to 1200 x 675, even in the media panel in Wordpress it shows them at 1200 x 675. So they somehow get shrunk to 922 when they are displayed on the page.

Comment: what you have in dashboard->setting->media->large size?

Comment: No, I meant when you click on the images in the media library it shows the specs. They are 1200 x 675, not 922px wide as mathius1 suspected the problem might be. In dashboard > settings > media the large size is set to max width and height 1024.

Comment: Are these images uploaded after you had set the size? Or have you tried regenerating the thumbnails?

p/s: This does not load: http://www.fredericdesign.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/bridgethegap/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that code elsewhere is changing what you are setting. Your best bet is to define your own thumbnail size, and then specify it when retrieving the thumbnail

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'myCrazySize', 960, 540, true );
}

get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'myCrazySize');
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by setting the post thumbnail size to 'full'. I am still confused as to what is setting (what I assume is) the large size to 922px wide. This is the code that did it, on the page template where the post_thumbnail is called:

```
<div class="img">
 <a title="<?=$title?>" href="<?=$site[0]?>">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
 </a>
 <span class="itemTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
</div>
```

The "full" in `<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>` being the addition.